# (Probably) trivial question about rmdir

Tags: unix, rm

I hope this isn't too trivial, but for some reason I can't get a simple command to execute.

I'm writing a file manipulation script and I have several directories called test, test2, etc each containing several files.
I type:
`rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty test*`

I get a prompt with no error messages as if the command executed cleanly. I `ls` the directory I'm in and get:
`test test2 test3 test4`

I know I'm missing something obvious; anyone have a clue what it is? Yes, I'm in the parent directory. Yes, the option is typed correctly -- I checked the manpage twice.

Comment: Solved by doing `rm -r test*` but I still want to know what's wrong. :-)

Comment: Does running it with --verbose shed any light on the situation?

Comment: if you want to ignore failing on empty, why not rm -rf test*? (edit: nevermind, you just commented about having fixed it)

Comment: @EricR Why f? Doesn't the f option go up? I don't think I'd want that.

Comment: @Yitzchak "-f ignore nonexistent files, never prompt". afaik there's no option to ascend with rm.

Comment: @EricR, right you are. I guess I'll remember the rest of the manpage now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty` does exactly what it says on the tin, it ignores failures when not empty; i.e., it does nothing.

An alternate solutions to your problem would be `rm -r` or `rm -rf` , using `-f` in order to "ignore nonexistent files, never prompt".

Comment: This is the best answer, it explains the ambiguity of the man page. @EricR, I would add other ways to do what the OP wants to do (`rm -rf`)

Comment: @MaxMackie, fixed. I had left them in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`rmdir` removes empty directories. It does not remove non-empty directories. There is no way to make it remove non-empty directories.

Answer (score 0):

rmdir does not remove non-empty folders at all.

Use `rm -rf ./test*` for this. But be very careful about the path you give rm